# How modify types of point for a ggplot density graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like plot around 5 density in grey (to print my plot) and these density are very near. In addition, if I just modify the type of lines, it is not clear. Therefore, I would like modify the type of points. Somebody have a solution ?
For the moment, I plot that :

```
# An example of data
df = data.frame(speed = c(80 + rnorm(n = 10, sd = 7),
                          100 + rnorm(n = 10, sd = 7),
                          90 + rnorm(n = 10, sd = 7)),
                vehicule = c(rep("bus",10), rep("moto",10), rep("car",10)))

# Graph with different types of lines but not different types of points
ggplot(df, aes(speed, linetype = vehicule)) +
geom_density(alpha = 0.4)
```

Or :

```
# Graph with different type of points but not density
ggplot(df, aes(speed, y = vehicule, linetype = vehicule)) +
geom_point(aes(shape=vehicule)) +
geom_density(alpha = 0.4) + 
scale_color_grey() +
scale_fill_grey()
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want suggestion how to plot this kind of data? How to plot density plots using same color? Or how to add points to density plots?

Comment: E.g. `ggplot(df, aes(vehicule, speed)) +
    geom_violin(fill = 1, alpha = 0.3) + geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0) + coord_flip()`

Comment: In others word, I would like add some little squares on one density, some little circles on one other density and some little triangles on the last density. I want to distinguish easily the different densities, if you are others solutions, I am interested.